# Calculate time differences

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I want to calculate time difference of a column in Excel, column data shown below:

08:06am-12:00pm
10:40am-11:30am
01:15pm-04:00pm

[image: Excel Column]

Please share any formula, reference or method to calculate time difference in Excel column.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,9,5)&" "&MID(A1,14,2))-VALUE(MID(A1,1,5)&" "&MID(A1,6,2))
```

Apply a number format to the cell of `hh:mm`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=TEXT(LEFT(RIGHT(A2,7),5),"hh:mm")+IF(MID(A2,14,1)="p",1/2,0)-TEXT(LEFT(A2,5),"[hh]:mm")+IF(MID(A2,6,1)="p",1/2,0)-IF(RIGHT(A2,7)="12:00pm",-0.5)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty simple, actually:

```
=TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2),SECOND(B2))-TIME(HOUR(C2),MINUTE(C2),SECOND(C2))
```

Where B2 and C2 both have times in them.

What it looks like there is that your column has BOTH times in it.  You will have to split those columns first.  Because the way you have it, the field will be interpreted as TEXT and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks! But the column in same.

Comment: That's what I said.  You have to split that column.  Because there is no way to do math on a string (TEXT).  You can use another formula to split the columns and run the math that way.  But that's a lot of extra work, and is still not the right way to do it.

Comment: `But that's a lot of extra work, and is still not the right way to do it.` Strange notion there. You used EIGHT function calls after manually splitting into two columns!